# Using Excel Formulas to return the count of non zero in a column

Tags: excel, formula

I spent half the day racking my brain and playing around with the formulas i know of in the excel world but I still cannot figure out a method to do this without using VBA coding. Hopefully someone out here would be able to help provide some guidance without the use of code.

[image: Excel Table]

The scenario is this and refers to the screenshot above:

Objective: Determine the number of non zero values in a particular month's column for every row that has an "exceptions" label.

The month is controlled by the user input cell.

Example: 
Total number of non zeros in Feb column is 6. 
Actual result that I am expecting: 3 (because there are three rows with "exceptions" label and we should count the total of those rows only.)

I've tried Index/Match/Countifs/lookups but just cannot find the right combination.

Closest I came to was using the screenshot below but that only returns the total number of non zeros in that table.

[image: Formula]

Just putting the question out there for any of the excel gurus to help.

Appreciate the time and thanks in advance!

Regards,
Stan

Comment: Does **Q6** contain ***Feb*** or a date formatted to display ***Feb*** ??

Comment: Q6 is the user input. Question has been solved as per below! Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not want volatile functions like offset or indirect, you can still do it with index (your formula isn't wrong at all). Just try this:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(F2:K7,,MATCH(G10,F1:K1,0)),">0",E2:E7,"exeptions")
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice indeed. I didn't know about the volatile thing, this is clearly a better way.

Comment: Cool it works!!! Thanks so much! Glad to know there are simpler functions out there